# Requesting recommendations for upgrading a feed to a sub-panel

Tags: wiring, subpanel, conduit

I have a small subpanel in my laundry room which feeds the laundry and HVAC equipment. It is currently on a 30A 2-pole GE THQP breaker. I had recurring problems with overload trips until I installed a start capacitor kit on my condensing unit. Since then there have been no overload trips, but the circuit is still more heavily loaded than I'd like. I want to upgrade it to 50 amps, still with a THQP breaker (no available spaces in the main panel).

I recently replaced the previous 1960s vintage subpanel and found that the ground and neutral were tied together. I corrected that and ran a temporary ground wire back to the service entrance. The current feeder is a 10/3 (without ground) UF cable which runs through the crawl space under the home. The crawl space is not readily accessible and any replacement would have to be fished through it. Alternately, I could run EMT through the attic (Texas summer heat...) and down the side of the house to the service entrance; when I had the walls open for the subpanel replacement I ran a 3/4" EMT "stub" to a point where I could access it to extend it. Either way it would be about a 30-40 foot run from the laundry panel to the service entrance including twists and turns.

I'm seeking recommendations for routing and sizing the new feeder. Thanks for your input.

Comment: "seeking recommendations" is usually considered far too broad. If you were to pick something and ask about that as a plan, you'd be more on topic here.

Comment: What is the Article 220 Load Calculation on the subpanel? Alternately what is the nameplate amp or VA figures from the hardwired loads? (for an electric dryer just use 5500 VA as that is standard).  How many square feet of livable space does it provide lighting and outlets for?  Does it power a 120V circuit in the laundry?

Answer (score 1):

3/4" EMT limits you to three 6 AWG THHN (conduit is ground) If the terminations are rated for 75°C (which is usual for breakers and panels) you can pick from that column in the NEC ampacity chart

Consideration of **thermal derate** due to `"Texas Summer Heat"`

The 90C insulation rating on THHN 6 AWG (used for thermal derate, not for base ampacity) permits 60A for Aluminum, 75A for copper. The thermal derating for 105-113°F is 0.87 on 90°C wire, 0.82 for 114-122°F so the actual ampacity of 6AWG aluminum is 52.2 or 49.2 at those temperatures. The next notch up of 123-131°F drops back to 45.6 amps for aluminum wire, while copper at that temperature is good for 57A.

1" EMT would allow 4 AWG aluminum for less wire cost with the same thermal budget as 6 AWG copper. Cable under the house would presumably see less heat, and not be subject to the limitation of the pre-installed 3/4" EMT. Depending on type of cable you may need to choose base ampacity for the 60°C column rather than 75°C

Comment: Texas attics get hotter than 131F, I would take that table further.   OP's constraint is using THQP "thin" breakers, which have a max ampacity of 50A and a max wire size of #4.